# Change image inside web user control (setting up onmouseover programmatically)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Okay, so I'm fairly new to web development (but not programming), and am trying to figure out the best way to implement a mouse over image swap inside a user control.

I've tried several solutions to similar problems on SO already, but my problem appears to be unique to User Controls. I have a (user control) NavigationNenu with 4 (user control) NavigationItems on them, and essentially the NavigationItem is this:

```
<div class="div_navImage">
    <asp:Image ID="navImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%this.DefaultImageUrl %>" CssClass="image_navImage" />
    <div id="divIconText" runat="server"/> 
 </div>
```

with this code behind:

```
Private ReadOnly Property NavImageElementId As String
    Get
        Return navImage.GetUniqueIDRelativeTo(Me.Parent.Parent).ToString().Replace("$"c, "_"c)
    End Get
End Property

<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
Public Property DefaultImageUrl As String

<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
Public Property HoverImageUrl As String

<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
Public Property IconText As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    navImage.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "updateImageToHover(" + NavImageElementId + ")")
    navImage.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "updateImageToDefault(" + NavImageElementId + ")")
    navImage.ImageUrl = "~\" & DefaultImageUrl
    divIconText.InnerText = IconText

End Sub
```

and the html for the nav menu:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="NavigationMenu.ascx.vb" Inherits="[internal stuff]" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/Common/NavigationItem.ascx" TagName="navItem" TagPrefix="ucNavItem" %>

<ucNavItem:navItem ID="home" DefaultImageUrl="Resources/home_default.png" HoverImageUrl="Resources/home_hover.png" IconText="home" runat="server" />
<ucNavItem:navItem ID="ideas" DefaultImageUrl="Resources/ideas_default.png" HoverImageUrl="Resources/ideas_hover.png" IconText="ideas" runat="server" />
<ucNavItem:navItem ID="data" DefaultImageUrl="Resources/data_default.png" HoverImageUrl="Resources/data_hover.png" IconText="data" runat="server" />
<ucNavItem:navItem ID="solutions" DefaultImageUrl="Resources/solutions_default.png" HoverImageUrl="Resources/solutions_hover.png" IconText="solutions" runat="server" />
```

The javascript has fluctuated a bit and I don't really have a working copy right now, but the best result I was able to achieve so far was on mouse over the icon would change to the proper image, but only of the last item in the navigation menu (ie item 1 would change to the hover over icon for item 4 when moused over), so it feels like some kind of scoping or instance issue (though I'm not entirely sure that those kind of issues exist in asp.net/JS/html land).

So, is there something different that needs done when working with JS and a repeated user control? Is there some other way I should be going about what I'm attempting to achieve? I've tried a bit of jquery also, but the samples I've worked with haven't really done anything, so I'm probably setting something up incorrectly there.

Any advice to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

forgot to point out - the reason I'm not doing a simple swap in the page load on:
   navImage.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "updateImageToHover(" + NavImageElementId + ")")

is because I want the image to change when the text is rolled over as well, and after I implement the JS swap, I will apply the solution to the text as well (but a solution which applies to the outer div would be most welcome as well).

EDIT 2:

JS that produces bad results:

```
 function updateImageToHover(fullName) {
    var hoverImageUrl =  '<%= HoverImageUrl%>';
    var navImage = document.getElementById(fullName.id);
    navImage.src = hoverImageUrl;
}
```

Comment: Are you needing backwards compatibility with old browsers like IE6?  If not, it seems you could do this in pure CSS and not need code at all.

Comment: That's not specifically a goal, no. Can you use variables in css? I want the vb code behind to have the urls stored. - Also, I just added the bottom section to original question.

Comment: Don't know if it would work for your situation, but I would have the code behind set CSS class names, not image URLs.  For example have the code set the CSS class of the control to "solutions", and have a "solutions" CSS class that sets the background images for the normal and :hover pseudo-class.

Comment: Adding the JS functions I was using to the original question...

Comment: I'll mess around with that idea. The only road block I think is getting the icon to change when the text is hovered over though (as well as when the icon is hovered over).

Comment: After a bit of thought, another design consideration is that the nav menu should be update-able via a DB table in the future (without adding new code), so I don't think coding specific CSS classes on a per-icon basis is going to viable long run either.

Though I will still play around with that idea to improve my css skills anyway.